# Используя node.js получить хеш-суммы файлов в папке и записать в текстовый файл

Tags: node.js, хеширование

На данный момент могу получить хеш только одного файла данным скриптом:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fd = fs.createReadStream('./archive.zip');
var hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
hash.setEncoding('hex');

fd.on('end', function() {
    hash.end();
    console.log(hash.read());
});

fd.pipe(hash);
```

Comment: И в чём проблема? Для списка файлов есть метод `readDir`(`readDirSync`), для проверки на файл `stat`(`statSync`).  https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения хеша всех файлов в директории, необходимо для начала получить список файлов, находящихся в текущей директории. Сделать это можно, используя синхронную функцию

```
fs.readdirSync(".")
```

которая принимает параметром имя директории и возвращает массив строк с именами файлов. Но в этом массиве вместе с именами файлов также будут и имена директорий, которые находятся в текущей директории. Считать требуется только хеши файлов, поэтому имена директорий слежует из массива удалить. Для этого можно применить к массиву имен метод reduce и сформировать новый массив, который будет содержать только имена файлов. Для определения, является ли сущность директорией можно использовать метод

```
fs.statSync
```

который принимает параметром имя и возвращает объект, содержащий информацию. Метод объекта

```
isFile
```

возвращает true, если объект является файлом

```
const files = fs.readdirSync(".").reduce((p, c) => {
    if (fs.statSync(c).isFile()) {
        p.push(c);
    }
    return p;
}, []);
```

После получения списка имен файлов можно определить функцию, которая будет считать хеш файла и записывать его в выходной файл. Так как метод рассчета хеша асинхронный, то эту функцию нельзя вызывать в цикле последовательно для всех файлов. Стоит применить рекурсивный вызов в точке, когда сохранение очередного хеша завершено. При этом рекурсивная функция будет принимать параметром индекс файла в массиве имен для которого следует рассчитать хеш. Запись получившихся хешей в выходной файл можно выполнить синхронным методом

```
fs.appendFileSync
```

который принимает два параметра: имя файла, в который будут записываться строка и строка для записи. Этот метод создает файл, если его еще не существует и пишет строку в конец файла.

В итоге получается следующий код

```
const fs = require("fs");
const crypto = require("crypto");

const files = fs.readdirSync(".").reduce((p, c) => {
    if (fs.statSync(c).isFile()) {
        p.push(c);
    }
    return p;
}, []);

(function makeHash(i) {
    const fd = fs.createReadStream(files[i]);
    const hash = crypto.createHash("md5");
    hash.setEncoding("hex");
    fd.on("end", () => {
        hash.end();
        fs.appendFileSync("hash", `${files[i++]}:${hash.read()}\n`);
        if (i < files.length) {
            makeHash(i);
        }
    });

    fd.pipe(hash);
})(0);
```

в результате работы которого в файле **hash** будут содержаться хеши всех файлов в текущей директории. Каждый файл будет представлен отдельной строкой в формате

```
имя файла:хеш файла
```

Comment: Я бы всё-таки использовал `statSync` вместо `lstatSync`.  Вряд ли автору нужен хеш ссылки на файл вместо хеша файла.

Comment: Ну и `isFile` вместо отрицания `isDirectory`

Comment: @Alexey Ten согласен. Поправил. Спасибо.